# How to fix the Error "Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'"

Tags: angular, typescript

Following a course made in Angular 4 while i'm using the latest version and i can't for the life of me figure out this problem.
i am getting an error in `products.component.ts` when trying to filter the products.

any help would be appreciated, i'm still new and this is my fourth day learning Angular.

```
Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'. 
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Product': title, price, category, imageUrl
```

**product.ts**

```
export interface Product {
    title: string;
    price: number;
    category: string;
    imageUrl: string;
}
```

**product.service.ts**

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './models/product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  create(product) {
    return this.db.list('/products').push(product);
  }



  getAll(){
    return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions =>
          actions.map(a => ({ key: a.key, ...a.payload.val() }))
        )
      );
  }

  get(productId) {
    return this.db.object('/products/' + productId);
  }

  update(productId, product) {
    return this.db.object('/products/' + productId).update(product);
  }

  delete(productId)
  {
    return this.db.object('/products/' + productId).remove();
  }

}
```

**products.component.ts**

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { CategoryService } from './../category.service';
import { ProductService } from './../product.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../models/product';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent {
  products: Product[];
  categories$: Observable<any[]>;
  category: string;
  filteredProducts: Product[];

  constructor(

    productService: ProductService, 
    categoryService: CategoryService,
    route : ActivatedRoute) {

    productService.getAll().subscribe(a => this.products = a); //error on this.products: 

    //"Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'."
    //  "Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Product': title, price, category, imageUrl"

    this.categories$ = categoryService.getAll();

    route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {

      this.category = params.get('category');

      this.filteredProducts = (this.category) ?
      this.products.filter(p => p.category === this.category) : this.products;

    });
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is happening because you did not specify the type of data that will be retrieved using the getAll() method.

TypeScript is a strongly typed language, so it tries to validate all types and assignments at compile time.

Try changing the erratic line with:

```
productService.getAll().subscribe((a: Product[]) => this.products = a);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but this does not work. I think i'm gonna drop this course and look for something that teaches me Angular8 instead of 4. In addition to being a noob to this, i have to spend hours of reading in the documentation and stackoverflow to fix small issues :X

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK `list` is a generic, you can and should provide the typing. Instead of

```
    return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges()
```

do

```
    return this.db.list<Product>('/products').snapshotChanges()
```

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this observable -

```
getAll(){
    return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions =>
          actions.map(a => ({ key: a.key, ...a.payload.val() }))
        )
      );
  }
```

You are mapping your actions array to an Array<{key, []}>.
While you are expecting an Array (i.e. Product[]).

So ensure to map the actions array to Array of Products (i.e. Array)
Try to change your code like this -

```
getAll(){
        return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges()
          .pipe(
            map(actions =>
              actions.map(a => {
                 title: <fill this from equivalent in a>,
                 price: <fill this from equivalent in a>,
                 category: <fill this from equivalent in a>,
                 imageUrl: <fill this from equivalent in a>
              })
            )
          );
      }
```

BTW, the problem is not in Angular 4 vs Angular 8 [The same example will give the same error in Angular8 as well]. This is how Typescript type checking works. If you would have written the same code in plain vanilla javascript, then you might not have seen any error at compile time but you would have seen unexpected behavior at run time. Here typescript is ensuring to catch errors at compile time as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

**product.ts**

```
export interface Product {
    key: string;
    title: string;
    price: number;
    category: string;
    imageUrl: string;
}
```

**products.component.ts**

```
import { ProductService } from './../../product.service';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-admin-products',
    templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './admin-products.component.css' ]
})
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    products: Product[];
    filteredProducts: Product[];
    subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(private productservice: ProductService) {
        this.subscription = this.productservice
        .getAll()
        .subscribe((products: Product[]) => (this.filteredProducts = this.products = products));
    }

    filter(query: string) {
        this.filteredProducts = query
        ? this.products.filter((p) => p.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()))
        : this.products;
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**products.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of filteredProducts">
    <td>{{ p.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ p.price }}</td>
    <td>
        <a [routerLink]="['/admin/admin-products/', p.key]">Edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If you can add some description with your answer will be great.

Answer (score 0):

This can change your life.

```
getAll() {
    return this.db.list<Product>('/products').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions =>
          actions.map(a => ({ key: a.key, ...a.payload.val() }))
        )
      );
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the solution? What does it do? How is it different compared to the code in the question?